transforming a grammar from EBNF to LL(2)
I have a grammar in EBNF and want to transform it into an LL(2) grammar. Should I omit A -> empty string ? And is there a scheme I can follow? So far I would just try to expand everything and see where there will be conflicts.

It is not possible in general because not all context-free languages can be generated by an LL(2) grammar. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155655/determining-if-a-grammar-can-be-converted-to-ll1-llk You cannot just remove rules that generate the empty string.

@reinierpost, can I encourage you to post that as an answer rather than a comment, so the question can be treated as answered and we can upvote your answer?  No need for an answer to contain anything more than you already wrote.

I would hope for some heuristics for constructing LL(2) grammars, even when they can't cover all cases.

thanks for your answers. I won't delete rules but add new ones and just expand all rules to see what set of first and follow symbols I get.
